# How to connect SQL Server Profiler to SQL Server Express?

Tags: sql, sql-server-express, sql-server-profiler

Is there any better way to profile a SQL Server Express instance than below?

I am doing the below:

1. Run the `sqllocaldb info` utility in the command prompt to find the instance name.
2. Run `sqllocaldb info v11.0` to find the "Instance Pipe Name"
3. Use the instance name (as below), connect to SQL Server Express from SQL Server Profiler

Comment: Please define 'better'? Do you mean easier? For a given installation the instance name is always the same so you only need to do this once (you should also know it from when you installed it?). Why do you need the pipe name to connect? Is this for a known installation of SQL Express or are you trying to automate this somehow? Instance and pipe names are also in the registry, the sql logs and the windows event logs if that is any easier.

Comment: I used the pipe name cause I was unable to connect with "(LocalDB)\v11.0"!

Comment: Can you add some more background to your question? Did you already create this DB with `sqllocaldb create`? What do you hope to achieve by doing this 'better'?

Comment: The DB was created in SQL Express thru SQL Studio. And the above mentioned steps I have followed to connect from the SQ Profiler to the SQL Express Database. My question is, is there any other way to connect to the SQL Express database thru SQL Profiler or that is the way what I have mentioned above.

Comment: To connect to SQL Express.. you at least need to tell it what to connect to (step 3). How else would you be able to connect? All I can say is steps 1 and 2 are redundant because you already know connection details.

Comment: That's the whole point, it doesn't connect to SQL by the name of the server, you have to use the "Instance Pipe Name". I guess you are loosing the whole context...!!

Comment: OK, now that I have done some research I see that this localdb only runs on named pipes and possibly generates a new named pipe every time. So from my reading, yes this is the only way to do it. Can you confirm that the pipe name in step 2 changes everytime? You could probably automate this in a batch file if you wanted. Interested?